# Error "Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC" when I run update_blastdb.pl

Tags: blast, perl

I encoutered some technical problem when learning BLAST as below:

After I use `conda install blast` to install ncbi-blast, and run the command:

`update_blastdb.pl --decompress 16SMicrobial`

the shell complains:

> Can't locate List/MoreUtils.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   List::MoreUtils module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/loc
>   al/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/li
>   b/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base .) at
>   /home/mck f111/miniconda3/envs/bioinfo/bin/update_blastdb.pl line 43.

After I run this command:

```
cpanm List::MoreUtils
```

It appears some installation happened, however, the complains are still there.
Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What operating system are you running this on? That looks like some sort of *nix, but is it Linux, macOS, UNIX, Ubuntu subsystem on Windows? Something else? Did you run the `cpanm` command as a regular user or as root? Did you see where it installed (it should be mentioned in the command's output)? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Install List::MoreUtils using the same user as blast.